Error C1041 in VS Code for C++, no .pdb in all of PC files
I'm working on a data science project that has both Python and C++ files, so I use VS Code as its a good IDE for both. Yesterday, I accidentally ran one of the C++ files and killed it during build. It contains multithreading if that is in any way relevant. Anyways, now I can't run any C++ files, I keep getting this same error:

Executing task: C/C++: cl.exe build active file

Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /FeD:\SCS\fullintegration.exe D:\SCS\fullintegration.cpp
fullintegration.cpp
D:\SCS\fullintegration.cpp: fatal error C1041: cannot open program database 'D:\SCS\vc140.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.  

I looked around for this vc140.pdb file found it in a different directory than the one I was running the file in (it was in the location of a header file, which also contains all of the C++ work related to the project, the main file was the first C++ file outside of this directory). I since have deleted the file, removed the C++ extension from VS Code and reinstalled it, added /FS to the configuration json file (can be found below). Nothing is working and I am unsure how to proceed with this.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: cl.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": ["/FS"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}

Edit:
I added the /FS flag to the task.json file as suggested, the following was the resulting error:  *  Executing task: C/C++: cl.exe build active file
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && cl.exe /FS
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34120 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.


try to restart your pc ... like completely, use the restart button. maybe a hanging process is holding it locked while other processes cannot modify it

You should edit the tasks.json not the launch.json

I restarted my PC since this issue, no luck. I just tried the task.json file flag there, this was the error produced from it:  *  Executing task: C/C++: cl.exe build active file
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && cl.exe /FS
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34120 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
Build finished with error(s).

The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.


Seems like you removed the 2 source file names from the args: with your change to tasks.json.

Why were there 2 different fullintegration.cpp files listed in your original build: D:\SCS\fullintegration.cpp fullintegration.cpp

no idea about the multiple fullintegration.cpp files listed, there is only one. I figured out the args issue, and added all of these given chatgpts suggestion: "/Zi", // Debug information
"/EHsc", // Exception handling
"/nologo", // Suppress compiler banner
"/FS", // Force write to .pdb
"/Fe${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe", // Output executable
"${file}" // The active file to compile

from these args, i am now facing this issue:
I am now working on this error: cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /FS /FeD:\SCS\fullintegration.exe D:\SCS\fullintegration.cpp
fullintegration.cpp
D:\SCS\fullintegration.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'D:\SCS\fullintegration.obj': No such file or directory

cl.exe /FS and missing source filename -- the error is pretty clear. Why do you make pain yourself with using VSCode when you have MS VS?

cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && cl.exe /FS was wrong because it had no source files listed and all the other arguments: /Zi /EHsc /nologo /FeD:\SCS\fullintegration.exe were removed.
